# Does Detonator get rid of poison?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The description for [Detonator](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Detonator) says it does 1 damage for every 1 poison on an enemy. If I use Detonator on a poisoned enemy, will it reset that enemy's poison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Detonator does not get rid of poison. If you use Detonator on an enemy with 5 poison, it will still have 5 poison after your attack.